# sqlite schema has quotes around table name after a table rename

Tags: sqlite, schema

I had to rename an existing table in my sqlite database using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE users RENAME TO widgets;
```

After running that command, when I check the schemas using the .schema command, this is what I see:

```
CREATE TABLE "widgets"(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, widget_tag varchar(10), destination varchar(100), class varchar(10), name varchar(255), grp active bit(1));
CREATE TABLE uu(id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, uu_name varchar(255), email varchar(255), active bit(1));
```

Notice the quotes around the table name.  I'm not sure if that's a bad thing or not.  My web application runs just fine and I'm able to update / delete / select records no problem.

Can someone tell me what these quotes are and if I need to worry ? 
Thanks.

Comment: `My web application runs just fine` - This is the answer. `I need to worry?` - No. Worry when things **don't** work.

Comment: Yes, there is that approach.  However, when this could impact many many users, I don't feel comfortable ignoring deltas, especially when I don't understand them.  Thought I'd better ask just to be safe.

Comment: Quotes are just a "safe" way the db manager automatically uses to define the table name (in case the user creates a table containing spaces, you know).

Comment: @DerGolem that makes sense.  I hadn't thought of that.  Thank you

Comment: Yes, there is nothing to worry about from correctness point of view. In my app, we do migration regularly and we use temp tables with renaming them quite often for migrations. When we create a clean db we don't do migration but instead directly creating the latest schema. I found this SQLite behavior is quite annoying when I automated comparison of clean schema with migrated schema for verification. These quotes make my life much more complicated then it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you have nothing to worry about.  The quotes simply define the name of the table as a string literal to SQLite.  You would only need to worry if the value came back with the double quotes in "widgets" escaped, which you would have seen in your schema check as ""widgets"".